# Script doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I cant understand what's wrong with my script and why even the first `alert` doesn't work?
http://jsfiddle.net/TULsL/17/

HTML:

```
<div id="listProducts">
    <input type="radio" class="selectItem" name="inch" id="inch-1" value="1" />
    <label for="inch-1">Имя: тостер, Цвет: серый, Тип: мелкая техника, Цена: <span class="priceIn">500</span>, Количество единиц на складе: 5</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" class="selectItem" name="inch" id="inch-2" value="4" />
    <label for="inch-2">Имя: миксер, Цвет: черный, Тип: мелкая техника, Цена: <span class="priceIn">300</span>, Количество единиц на складе: 3</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" class="selectItem" name="inch" id="inch-3" value="5" />
    <label for="inch-3">Имя: электрочайник, Цвет: белый, Тип: мелкая техника, Цена: <span class="priceIn">320</span>, Количество единиц на складе: 2</label>
    <br/>
</div>
<input type="text" id="priceValue" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listProducts input:radio:checked']).click(function () {
        alert('test');
        var text = $(this).next('label').find('.priceIn').html();
        alert(text);
        $('#priceValue').text(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/TULsL/25/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the ] and the :checked and the text(text) should be val(text)

Original:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listProducts input:radio:checked']).click(function () {
        alert('test');
        var text = $(this).next('label').find('.priceIn').html();
        alert(text);
        $('#priceValue').text(text);
    });
});
```

Correct:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#listProducts input:radio').click(function () {
        alert('test');
        var text = $(this).next('label').find('.priceIn').html();
        alert(text);
        $('#priceValue').val(text);
    });
});
```

Comment: I have found, I was need to remove `:checked` also and replace `$('#priceValue').text(text);` with `$('#priceValue').val(text);`

Comment: Well glad you found it, i added it to my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You make mistake two one is ']' and checked property..

```
$('#listProducts input:radio').click(function () {
            alert('test');
            var text = $(this).next('label').find('.priceIn').html();
            alert(text);
            $('#priceValue').val(text);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You forget `'` at the end.

```
 $('#listProducts input:radio:checked]')
                   -------------------^--
```

also just use `$('#listProducts input:radio]')` instead of

```
$('#listProducts input:radio:checked]')
```

Comment: but then you open quote twice and close it once, or open once and close twice, is that supposed to be?

Comment: @fonZ ohh nice catch...i forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // an extra ] at the end of the selector and you were registering the handler to only the checked radio button, in this case when the page loads there are no radio button which is checked
    $('#listProducts input:radio').change(function () {
        alert('test');
        var text = $(this).next('label').find('.priceIn').html();
        alert(text);
        $('#priceValue').text(text);
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/s23h2/)

Also it is better to use change handler instead of click handler